# How to automatically update a table's data in a Rails application view without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have rails app that I use as an API for a mobile application. The app has a  **Driver** model with a **status** and location (**lat**, **lon**) properties which can be toggled from the mobile application. I have an index view (*index.html.erb*) for the Driver model which can be viewed by the Admin (from a browser) and it shows a table with the Drivers' name, their statuses and other properties. I wanted the statuses and locations on this HTML page to get updated automatically (without refreshing the page), if they are changed from the mobile app while the Admin is viewing it.

I know that this can be done using javascript or jQuery and that it would involve loading data from the server periodically, comparing it too the current values displayed and then updating the mismatched value. However I do not have any experience in either JS or jQuery and I could not find any good tutorial that explains how to integrate rails with these features step by step.

Here is the controller:

app/controllers/drivers_controller.rb

```
class DriversController < ApplicationController

  # GET /drivers
  # GET /drivers.json
  def index
    @drivers = Driver.all.order(:id)

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html 
       format.json { render :json => @drivers.to_json(only: [:id, :name, :contact, :lat, :lon, :status]), status: 200 }
    end
  end

end
```

The controller has other functions too that are related to the API and manipulating the database.

app/views/drivers/index.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Location</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @drivers.each do |driver| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= driver.id %></td>
        <td><%= driver.name %></td>
        <td><%= driver.contact %></td>
        <td>
          <% if driver.status == 0 %>
            Uninitialised Account
          <% elsif driver.status == 1 %>
            Available For Hire
          <% elsif driver.status == 2 %>
            Hired
          <% elsif driver.status == 3 %>
            Off Duty
          <% elsif driver.status == 4 %>
            Unknown  
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>(<%= driver.lat %>,  <%= driver.lon %>)/td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', driver_path(driver), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_driver_path(driver), class: 'btn btn-info btn-xs' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', driver, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this driver\'s record?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to new_driver_path, class: 'btn btn-success' do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New Driver
<% end %>
```

I have integrated bootstrap with my app too.

Answer (score 1):

You need **sockets** to implement this logic.

`Pusher` is a good gem for this purpose. It's really easy to implement it. You can read more about it here - https://pusher.com/

**Example:**

Push data from your controller to the view:

```
Pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
  message: 'hello world'
});
```

In your view you should wait for pushed event from the server:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert('Received my-event with message: ' + data.message);
});
```